# Calculate frequencies

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
Expt    Replicate
A       1
A       2
A       3
B       1
B       2
B       3
C       1
C       2
C       3
C       4
```

I want to return the number of replicates for each experiment. Like this:

```
Expt    #Reps
A       3
B       3
C       4
```

This has got to be super simple, but I have tried some things like

```
ddply(df, Expt, .fun=max(Replicate))
```

with no luck. Please help.

Comment: I think the terminology here is a bit confusing. You're really trying to build a one-way contingency table, not find the "max" by group. "max" generally refers to finding the maximum or minimum value from an input vector and has nothing to do with the total number of observations for that group.

Comment: I agree that the terminology is not correct. Perhaps *How do I count the number replicates per factor* would be a better title (as this is what the accepted answer returns. (My answer is edited to reflect this)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

another simple way:

```
 summary(df[,1]) #where df is your data frame and you want the 1st column counts ("Expt")
```

Note: the 1st column is a `factor` and this applies to any columns which are `factor`

Answer (score 4):

`table` is your friend. You even need not second column, `table` will count items in first column for you:

```
> x <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')
> x
 [1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C"
> table(x)
x
A B C 
3 3 4
```

Answer (score 4):

A `data.table` solution (to counting the number of replicates)

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df[,list(max = .N),by='Expt']
```

If you want the maximum a column then use

```
df[,list(max = max(Replicate)),by='Expt']
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone. I also found this works:

```
aggregate(as.numeric(df$Replicate), list(exptCount=df$expt),max)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve your goal is

```
> df <- data.frame(Expt = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), c(3,3,4)), Replicate = append(rep(1:3, 3), 4, 10))
> tapply(df$Replicate, df$Expt, max)
A B C 
3 3 4
```

But if you really want to use `ddply`, you can try:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(Expt),numcolwise(max))
```